# Adding (&) dynamically in strings in oracle without using SET DEFINE OFF

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL script in which I have to insert ampersand (&) and I am unaware of the position it is in.  I am running this SQL script from the environment where I cannot use SET DEFINE OFF. I can only run SQL insert, select, update and delete.

Comment: What client are you running the script through, and why can't you just add that `set` command to the script? If you're executing individual statements through, say. JDBC then why are the ampersands a problem - substitution variables are a client thing, not something inherently interpreted in SQL?

Comment: I am using this thing in interface provided to me where i can run insert command only, there is no provision of giving set define off

Comment: OK, so what is that interface doing? Is it calling SQL\*Plus to run each statement individually? (You may be able to add the `set` in `login.sql`, or get whoever owns the interface to do that). But do you actually have a problem with ampersands being interpreted as substitution variables - or are you anticipating that you might?

Comment: Yes I am having problem with ampersands being interpreted as substitution variables. Yes the SQL run each statement individually.

Answer (score 0):

May be you could escape `&` by using `chr(38)` instead.

```
select chr(38) as res  from dual
```

Results in

```
res 
&
```

You could concatenate this symbol to any string in whatever position:

```
select  'M '  || chr(38) || ' S' as res  from dual
```

Results in

```
res 
M & S
```

Comment: This won't work as there is no definite position of &. It can come in any position of the string

Comment: @SantoshShrestha Can't you process the statements before submitting it to your restricted 'environment'?  If you can process the statement then you could transform any string containing ampersand to concatenations of the strings and `chr(38)` symbol. But if you cannot process at all before running your statements  and you cannot use `SET DEFINE OFF` ... then, I guess,  you are in real trouble...

Comment: I guess I am so have raised this question for my solution